# Eval math formula string with ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, math, eval

How can I eval Math formulas with AS3?
Nothing fancy, things like `(10/3)*4+10`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While you could use a huge eval lib like [D.eval](http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/) or [AS3Eval](http://eval.hurlant.com/), all you really need is something like this simple  [MathParser](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/mathparser/bkde.zip) ([More info about the MathParser](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/mathparser/mp1.html))

Here's how you'd use the MathParser:

```
package {
    import bkde.as3.parsers.*;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class MathTest extends Sprite {
        public function MathTest() {
            var parser:MathParser = new MathParser([]);
            var compiledObj:CompiledObject = parser.doCompile("(10/3)*4+10");
            var answer:Number = parser.doEval(compiledObj.PolishArray, []);

            // EDIT: In case you wanted variables
            var xyParser:MathParser = new MathParser(["x", "y"]);
            var xyCompiledObj:CompiledObject = xyParser.doCompile("(x/3)*y+10");
            var xyAnswer:Number = xyParser.doEval(xyCompiledObj.PolishArray, [10, 4]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ActionScript 3 no longer supports eval function out-of-the-box, what you suggested might only work in ActionScript 2.

Comment: Even in AS2 that would not have worked. Eval can only be used to access parameters of an objects - it's useless.

Comment: Completely reworked. I used an old and apparently incorrect reference when answering the first time. Hopefully, you'll reconsider the down votes (though if you plan on leaving it down, let me know what more I could do to provide a better answer)

Answer (score 4):

I believe [D.eval API](http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/index.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid using libraries, you could try using the `ExternalInterface.call` to get access to Javascript's eval function.

For example:

```
var formula:String = '1+1';
var result:* = ExternalInterface.call('eval', formula);
```

You may want to check if `result == 'undefined'` as that would signify an error in the formula syntax.

Comment: The app doesn't run in a browser window, will that still work?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure -- I don't have much experience with AS3 outside of the browser. You might be better off using a 3rd party library in that case. Where is this going to run?

Comment: On the desktop. Not sure I can use JS there although it does have a WebKit distribution bundled.